# How can a touch be intercepted and some custom action perform for some elements but the usual behaviour happen for others?

Tags: javascript

I'm loading html pages on iOS and want to intercept the user touching the screen anywhere that isn't an anchor/link/button etc. and perform some action, however if the touch on a link etc. I want the action/behaviour associated with that to be performed as usual.
In order to intercept the touches I am executing the following script:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');  
script.type = 'text/javascript';  
script.text = window.onload = function addListener() {
alert('adding listener');

function init() {
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) 
            {
                    if (['A', 'BUTTON', 'AREA'].indexOf(e.target.tagName) === -1) 
                    {
                          e.preventDefault();
                          e.stopPropagation();
                          invokeObjectiveC("ontouchstart:");
                    }
            }, false);
}

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    init();
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
    }
 }
function invokeObjectiveC(action) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", action);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

This works up to a point, InvokeObjectiveC() is being called when I want it to, but if the html contains a section such as this:

```
    <div id="B145" class="abutton w80xh42" >
        <map name="B145_map" id="B145_map" >
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,80,42" href="XYZ:Action_Test45id" alt="" />
        </map>
        <img id="B145_img" src="transparent_80x42.png" usemap="B145_map" alt="" />
    </div>
```

then when the button is touched nothing happens - but it would if my script wasn't executed. So my script code is interfering with the normal behaviour if the user clicks on a button or link etc. How can I get my script to intercept if the user touches somewhere which isn't a button/link etc. but not affect other things when the user touches/clicks a button/link etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used delegation in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/DdcJJ/6/  to achieve the result, using the YUI JavaScript library. Pretty easy stuff, you'll see when you click the AREA element that a JavaScript is run, from that element's href value.

I did try to use YUI's selector utility to make all elements except the AREA tag a delegation target, which is maybe cleaner but as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/tAt4m/1/  we capture both the delegation event (because MAP wraps AREA) and the default event.

I guess you could achieve the same result without a JavaScript library, but there's a proof of concept to work with anyhow!

Comment: The YUI 'click' event will capture touches, too, btw.